# Why is my bash script not receiving the exit code from umount?

Tags: bash, script

This is my first time attempting to write a long bash script to manage a server I run, and when using **"set -ex"** the script exits when umount fails.  I thought my if statement would catch it but the script exits before echo is fired.

What am I overlooking here?

```
umount $MOUNTPATH
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];
then
  /bin/echo "Failed to unmount!  Already unmounted?"
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set -e` will make the shell exit as soon as a command fails. That is, as soon as the `unmount` command finishes. The `if` cannot catch it, since the script exits before it even gets to the `if`. You can fix this by putting the `unmount` command *in* the if condition (negated with `!` to make it run the `then` clause if the unmount fails, rather than if it succeeds):

```
if ! unmount $MOUNTPATH; then
    /bin/echo "Failed to unmount!  Already unmounted?"
fi
```

Comment: Ah ok, I did not realize this either.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have a semi-colon after your if statement.

```
umount $MOUNTPATH
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
  /bin/echo "Failed to unmount!  Already unmounted?"
fi
```

That should fix it.

Sources: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/If_structures_to_execute_code_based_on_a_condition

Comment: I'll have to read up more, I thought the semi-colon was necessary. I see now that's only if i put then on the same line. Thank you.

Comment: Added a link to for a pretty good tutorial on conditionals in bash

Comment: I am also going to point out that Gordon Davisson's [answer](http://superuser.com/a/506772/161569) is probably more correct than mine. I would try that as it seems neater.